# Should I use font-size: 0 for image links?

Tags: html, css, seo

When styling a link with a background image, where the link has text in it which is replaced with text in the image, is it OK SEO-wise to set the font-size to 0 to avoid the text being over the image?

Like this:

```
<a href="htp://google.com" title="Google, the Best Search Engine!" class="googleLink"> Google </a>

<style>
    .googleLink {
        display: block; height: 40px; width: 40px;
        background: url('googleLinkImage-40x40.png') no-repeat;
        font-size: 0;
    }
<style>
```

I understand font size 0 is bad if you're abusing it to hide keywords, but does this technique hurt SEO when used sincerely?.

Thanks.

Comment: ... sounds like you know the answer already. As long as you have a good story for explaining to client why their site got blacklisted by Google, you might be ok ;-) It's a 2 part question though, the second being 'How to undo getting blacklisted by a search engine'

Comment: I would not overestimate the impact of SEO for such small details. Search engines know what is the `title` attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The important thing here is using your alt <strike>tag</strike> attribute for SEO, Google [recommends it this way](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBLvn_WkDJ4).

Having said that there are several css techniques for this. The one i recommend one is using `text-indent: -99999em;` instead of decresing the `font-size`.

Comment: it's an `alt` *attribute*, not a tag! And `alt` is only applicable to `<img>` tags. But a `title` attribute is also great, and it works on all elements.

Comment: @Spudley thanks for the heads up! i had tags in my head for some reason

Comment: Note that if you use a negative `text-indent` on a link, you should also specify `overflow: hidden` on the link.  Otherwise when the link gets focus, the focus lines will extend off the edge of the screen to wrap around the off-screen text.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know `overflow: auto` could hide the outline, and that's why I didn't like using it.

Comment: How is `text-indent: -99999em;` any better from `font-size:0`?

Answer (score 8):

When it comes to SEO, no-one *really* knows what's good or not, because neither Google nor Microsoft actually tell anyone exactly how things affect your rankings.

SEO "experts" like to watch Google and Bing, etc and try to see what effect different techniques have; they can see what sites get good rankings, and look at those sites to see what they're doing differently to those around them.

The really good SEO experts can actually do quite well at working out some of the key things to do to make a difference. But most of the so called "experts" are really just repeating things they've heard other people saying.

The one really important thing to know is that no matter what works well now, you need to also consider what will work in the future.

Google in particular have been known to adjust their algorithms very deliberately to punish SEO techniques that they consider to be "cheating". Sneaky tricks that were successfully getting sites to the top of the list suddenly changed into causing them to disappear into oblivion.

My advice therefore is as follows: I can't tell you whether this specific trick will or will not help your SEO score. I don't claim to be an expert in the field. But I will say that any time it feels like you're being sneaky in order to gain SEO points, it's likely to be a short-term gain at best, and there's a good chance it'll actually cause problems for you later on.

So if you think this feels like a sneaky trick that Google might take offence to, then you might want to think twice about it. Would a `title` attribute not be sufficient? (they're great for SEO, apparently)

On the other hand, if it feels to you like a legitimate way of hiding text which you want to be in the page content but not displayed, then go ahead with it.

As yourself: What would Google do?  ;-)

Comment: If I could mark two answers as correct I would, but the other has an alternative solution more helpful to people looking for the better-safe-than-sorry method. Thanks!